# Libcurl for ARM architecture

Tags: arm, libcurl, verifone

I'm cross compiling on Windows 7 and I use this compiler:

```
gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03\bin\arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe
```

I want to use libcurl for some HTTP requests but when I link using -libcurl I get the infamous message that the linker couldn't find that library. I tried searching on the internet for the correct library for this architecture (ARMHF) but I can't find anything. Or maybe I did find it but I'm doing things wrong? My linking call is long but here it is:

This is the one that works, if I add -libcurl or anything related it breaks...

```
C:\vde\toolchains\windows\vos2\gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03\bin\arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe -o out\RefApp -Wl,-rpath=C:\vde\SDKs\vos2\vos2-sdk-winx86-release-31010800\vos2\usr\lib -Wl,-r
path=C:\vde\SDKs\vos2\vos2-sdk-winx86-release-31010800\vos2\usr\local\lib -Wl,-rpath=C:\vde\SDKs\vos2\vos2-sdk-winx86-release-31010800\vos2\lib -Wl,-rpath=C:\vde\SDKs\vos2\vos2-sdk-winx86-release-3101
0800\vos2\usr\local\lib\svcmgr C:\desarrollo\corvet\out\corvet.a -LC:\desarrollo\RefApp\lib -LC:\vde\SDKs\vos2\vos2-sdk-winx86-release-31010800\vos2\usr\local\lib -LC:\vde\SDKs\vos2\vos2-sdk-winx86-re
lease-31010800\vos2\lib -LC:\vde\SDKs\vos2\vos2-sdk-winx86-release-31010800\vos2\usr\local\lib\svcmgr  -LC:\vde\ADKs\adk-full-4.6.5-610\vos2\lib -L -LC:\desarrollo\corvet\out -lrt -llog -lvfiguiprt -l
vfiipc -lTLV_Util -lpthread -lvfiplatforminfo -lsvc_utility -lvfibuzzer -lsvc_powermngt -lsvc_led -lvfisysinfo -lvfisysbar -lsqlite -lexpat -linf -lcom -levt -ltecclient -lmsrclient -lEMV_CT_Link -lEM
V_CT_Client -lEMV_CTLS_Link -lEMV_CTLS_Client -lNFC_Framework -lNFC_Client -lsvc_tms -lUtils -lseccmd-static -lsvc_sound -lccp -lcrypto -lsec -lseccmd-static -lsecins -lvfisvc -lvfisyspm -lvfimac -lvf
isec -lAdkCapX
```

I also tried downloading some libcurl libraries I found on debian page and that were supposedly for ARMHF, put them in some folder and used -L(routetofolder) but that didn't work either.

Hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: there is a lot of embedded architecture and platforms and compiled binaries just provide for a famous platform like Debian based distro/Windows, etc. in your case you need to build your library from the source.get libcurl sources, set your config based on your LD, AS, etc. address and cross-compile it from sources. I do the same for some other EFTPOS brands before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, libcurl is there in what you get from the vendor (if you look at /usr/lib you will find it there). It's a problem with your linking.

You might want to try looking at how dynamic libraries dependencies are resolved at linking and later at runtime on linux systems. It will also help you understand what may be happening on vos2 platform when you will try using your own dynamic libraries that may have conflicting names and linker can resolve them to something existing on the same device but at a location that you might not have permissions to read, because it belongs to different usrXX or sysXX.

Reading /etc/ld.so.conf from the device will help you understand the locations and search order done by dynamic linker. You can get the file from the device or simply find it in OS.rfsbundle (look in skeletonfs) and set your linking options right. I think it's not normally distributed with sysroot by the vendor but you can manually add it.